# How does this switch do the QoS?

Tags: qos

I wonder at what layer does this switch do the QoS, as it seems to be a layer 2 switch.  My understanding is that a switch should look into upper layers 3 to 7 to be able to do QoS.

Cisco Small Business SG 102-24 Switch

https://business.currys.co.uk/catalogue/computing/servers-networking/networking/switches/cisco-small-business-sg-102-24-switch-24-ports-unmanaged-rack-mountable/P157411P

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Ethernet link layer, common 802.1Q "VLAN" tags can be used to indicate eight QoS classes using a 3-bit "802.1p Priority Code Point" field. (Tags with a VLAN ID of 0 are used to indicate only priority on the native/untagged VLAN.)

But many switches *do* understand common L3 protocol headers, even if they don't make switching decisions based on L3 addresses – for example, they can read the DSCP field from IPv4 headers and generally also from IPv6, converting them to 802.1p QoS classes (or sometimes even filling in new DSCP values).

(Similarly, L2 switches will also look at IP source/destination addresses or the IPv6 "Flow ID" field to properly distribute flows across bonded links; some switches even understand TCP and UDP headers to extract the port numbers for that purpose.)

Comment: So this switch may be reading headers at OSI Layers 2, 3 or even 4 even though it's an unmanaged switch that doesn't do VLANs.  Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Comment: As an unmanaged switch, it probably just reads 802.1p tags, which are assigned by something else, and imposes some hardcoded priorities (if at all). It won't be reading DSCP as the mapping isn't always fixed (managed switches have configuration for mapping DSCP to 802.1p).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer 